# Show that $f_{M} : R^{2}/Z^{2}= T^{2}→ T^{2}$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Let $M$ be the following matrix: $M= (\begin{matrix}
2 & 1\\
1 & 1 \end{matrix})$. Show that $f_{M} : R^{2}/Z^{2}= T^{2}→ T^{2}$ is a homeomorphism.

Proof. Let $M= (\begin{matrix}
2 & 1\\
1 & 1 \end{matrix})$. So, $M^{-1}= (\begin{matrix}
1 & -1\\
-1 & 2 \end{matrix})$ Let $M: R^{2} \rightarrow R^{2}$ be a function defined by $M(x,y)=(2x+y, x+y)$.  Similarly, $M^{-1}: R^{2} \rightarrow R^{2}$ be a function defined by $M(x,y)=(x-y, -x+2y)$. Now let $q: R^{2} \rightarrow R^{2}/Z^{2}$ defined by $(x,y)=[(x,y)]$ (takes a point to its equivalence class). Give $R^{2}/Z^{2}$ the quotient topology.  Then $q$ is continuous and $q$o$M:R^{2} \rightarrow R^{2}/Z^{2}$ is continuous. (Why do we need this entire paragraph? Please explain.)

Let $f_{M}: R^{2}/Z^{2} \rightarrow R^{2}/Z^{2}$ defined by  $f_{M}([(x,y)])=q$o$M(x,y)=[M(x,y)]$ and $f_{M}^{-1}: R^{2}/Z^{2} \rightarrow R^{2}/Z^{2}$ defined by  $f_{M}^{-1}([(x,y)])=[M^{-1}(x,y)]$.

So, $f_{M}^{-1}$o$f_{M}=f_{M}^{-1}([M(x,y])=[M^{-1}M(x,y)]=[(x,y)]$.

Hence, $f_{M}^{-1}, f_{M}$ are continuous inverses of each other. (I understand that we need $f$ and $f^{-1}$ to show homemorphism, but what about showing that f is a bijection? Have we shown this?)  Thus, $f_{M}$ is homeomorphic.

This proof was in my notes but I don't really understand it and know if it's correct. Please explain all your steps in your explanation.  I'm very new to topology so please don't assume I know much.